# How to use paginate in the model::list method for combo in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I would like to know what is the way to paginate my combo of charges; it comes from my database description column, with all rows but I just want to show some of them.

Below is the method I'm using for that purpose:

```
// VIEW TO REGISTER USERS
public function VistaRegistraUsuario()
{
  $id_franquicia_usuario = Session::get('id_franquicia');
  $charges = charges_users::lists('descripcion', 'id'); // COMBO OF CHARGES

  return view('auth.register', compact('charges', 'id_franquicia_usuario'));
}// END VIEW
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this?

Comment: check my answer bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's a question of `pagination` I assume as you need to show some of the "Combo of Charges" in other words `pagination`

use `list` with Laravel's out of the box `pagination` like this

```
public function VistaRegistraUsuario()
{

  $id_franquicia_usuario = Session::get('id_franquicia');
  $charges = charges_users::lists('descripcion', 'id')->paginate(15); // IF YOU NEED TO RENDER 15 COMBO OF CHARGES ON FIRST PAGE

  return view('auth.register', compact('charges', 'id_franquicia_usuario'));
}
```

Refer: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination)

Comment: Thank you. However, i still didnt test this, i have been busy in the work. But i am 90% sure that your answer will help me.

Comment: pleasure if you found any doubt u can ask also upvote the answer :)